# Fabric encountering auth issue with paramiko

Tags: python, fabric, paramiko

So while troubleshooting recently, some changes to my python environment occurred. I'm under the impression I have everything back to rights, but that may not always be the case.
My fab commands all seem to be failing, including with very simple tests. It seems as though it's an issue with key handling / userpass fallback with paramiko.

For instance, with this relatively simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from fabric.api import *
from fabric import exceptions
import paramiko
from sys import argv
import re
import os
import getpass

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

failed_hosts = {}

def run_command(Command):
    try:
#        print_env('run_command', Command)
#        print_transport()
        output = run(Command, shell = False)
        return output
    except exceptions.NetworkError as e:
        print "Error encountered for %s: %s" % (env.host_string, e)
        failed_hosts[env.host_string] = e

def test_ver():
    result=run_command('sh ver')
    print result
```

I get:

> ca-cmacnevi-mac:~ christian.macnevin$ fab -f fabtest.py test_ver -u
>   admin No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for
>   connection: cisco_switch [cisco_switch] run: sh ver
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x3d9da90L
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring:
>   SSH-2.0-paramiko_1.17.2 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote
>   version/idstring: SSH-2.0-Cisco-1.25 INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected
>   (version 2.0, client Cisco-1.25) DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex
>   algos:[u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa'] client
>   encrypt:[u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc']
>   server encrypt:[u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'aes192-cbc',
>   u'aes256-cbc'] client mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5',
>   u'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96',
>   u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:[u'none'] server
>   compress:[u'none'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex
>   follows?False DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed:
>   diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed:
>   aes128-cbc DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-md5
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexGroup1 specified hash_algo
>    DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to
>   new keys ... DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key
>   d0f5d22e756685a3640d3a24ec18bb6c DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is
>   OK DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Authentication type (publickey) not
>   permitted. DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Allowed methods: [u'password']
>   [cisco_switch] Passphrase for private key: 
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x3dc6e50L
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring:
>   SSH-2.0-paramiko_1.17.2 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote
>   version/idstring: SSH-2.0-Cisco-1.25 INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected
>   (version 2.0, client Cisco-1.25) DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex
>   algos:[u'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:[u'ssh-rsa'] client
>   encrypt:[u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'aes192-cbc', u'aes256-cbc']
>   server encrypt:[u'aes128-cbc', u'3des-cbc', u'aes192-cbc',
>   u'aes256-cbc'] client mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96', u'hmac-md5',
>   u'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:[u'hmac-sha1', u'hmac-sha1-96',
>   u'hmac-md5', u'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:[u'none'] server
>   compress:[u'none'] client lang:[u''] server lang:[u''] kex
>   follows?False DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed:
>   diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed:
>   aes128-cbc DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-md5
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex engine KexGroup1 specified hash_algo
>    DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Switch to
>   new keys ... DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying SSH agent key
>   d0f5d22e756685a3640d3a24ec18bb6c DEBUG:paramiko.transport:userauth is
>   OK DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Authentication type (publickey) not
>   permitted. DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Allowed methods: [u'password']
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Trying discovered key
>   d014d32e356785aa628d3aa44cd6b265 in
>   /Users/christian.macnevin/.ssh/id_rsa
>   INFO:paramiko.transport:Disconnect (code 2): Protocol error: expected
>   packet type 50, got 5 Error encountered for cisco_switch: No existing
>   session DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread None
>
> Done.

I've seen some advice suggesting setting paramiko's 'look_for_keys' to False, but either got that wrong or it didn't help. And this all seemed to work just fine a few days ago, so I suspect there's something else at play.

Relevant:

fab --version
Fabric 1.12.0
Paramiko 1.17.2

python --version
Python 2.7.12

Comment: I didn’t see any hosts specified in either your fabfile or in your command.  Try `fab --host=<name of host> test_ver`.  Also, make sure to decorate tasks with the `@task` decorator.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. For this test, I stripped out everything I could, so I specify hosts on the command line. I'll add the @task in, but I can state that it hasn't had an effect in the file where I first encountered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, a pile more uninstalling and reinstalling and restarting did the trick. In short, it seems that paramiko was in a bad state and basic troubleshooting of the system fixed things. Thanks for the advice!